# JavaScript call functions

Tags: javascript, function, callstack

Could anyone explain me how does it works ?

```
console.log(func(10));
// 20
var func = function(x) {
    return x * x;
}

console.log(func(10));
// 100
var func = function(x) {
    return x + x;
}
```

I wanted to know how computer reads it? Please explain as easy as it is possible.

**EDIT:**
I'm asking because I found in the book "Eloquent Javascript" something like this:

```
console.log("The future says:", future());

function future() {
  return "We STILL have no flying cars.";
}
```

And he says:

> This code works, even though the function is defined below the code
>   that uses it. This is because function declarations are not part of
>   the regular top-to-bottom flow of control. They are conceptually moved
>   to the top of their scope and can be used by all the code in that
>   scope. This is sometimes useful because it gives us the freedom to
>   order code in a way that seems meaningful, without worrying about
>   having to define all functions above their first use.

Comment: As it is above, it *doesn't* work. It fails on the first line, because you can't call `undefined` as a function, but that's the value `func` has on the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Re your edit, see below under the divider.

The code as you've given it *won't* work. We can reorder it a bit to make it work, though:

```
var func = function(x) {
    return x * x;
};
console.log(func(10)); // 100

var func = function(x) {
    return x + x;
};
console.log(func(10)); // 20
```

Here's what happens with the above:

1. *Before* any step-by-step execution of the code, the browser scans the code for `var` declarations. It finds the first `var func` and so it creates a variable in the current context with that name. Then it finds the second `var`, but as the name is the same, it does nothing with the second one. At this point, `func` has the value `undefined`. (This bit where it does `var` in advance is called "var hoisting.")

   Now, step-by-step execution of the code begins.
2. The engine assigns a function to the `func` variable.
3. The engine calls `func`, passing in `10`. `func` returns `10 * 10` (`100`); the engine passes that value into `console.log`, which writes it out.
4. The engine assigns a new function to the `func` variable.
5. The engine calls `func`, passing in `10`. `func` returns `10 + 10` (`200`); the engine passes that value into `console.log`, which writes it out.

---

So what's wrong with the code as you've shown it? Here's how the engine runs the code as it is in the question:

1. *Before* any step-by-step execution of the code, the browser scans the code for `var` declarations and creates the variables as in #1 above.

   Now, step-by-step execution of the code begins.
2. The engine tries to call `func`, but the value in `func` is currently `undefined`, and so it fails with an error.

---

**Re your edit:** The code you've posted from Eloquent JavaScript is very different:

```
console.log("The future says:", future());

function future() {
  return "We STILL have no flying cars.";
}
```

That uses a *function declaration*, whereas your earlier code used *function expressions*. [This question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) go into detail, but declarations and expressions, even though they look *really similar*, behave very differently from one another. Here's the order of things with the above:

1. The JavaScript engine scans through the code looking for function declarations and processes them in source-code order. So it sees `function future() { ... }` and creates the function, associating it with the in-scope identifer `future`. This is called "function declaration hoisting" and it's a bit like `var` hoisting above, because it happens before any step-by-step code is done.

   Then the step-by-step execution begins.
2. The engine calls the `future` function, gets its return value, and then calls `console.log` using that return value.

Comment: Thank you :). Now I understand. I thought that function func() {} is equal to var func = function() {} :)

Comment: @Steave: Ah yes, *very* slight difference in syntax, [very big difference in what happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname).